# How to use form and ng-form together?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I want to use form and ng-form together. I have a markup like this:

```
<form 
name="createCampaignForm"
ng-submit="submitCreateCampaignForm(createCampaignForm.$valid)"
novalidate>
<myinput
  form="createCampaignForm"
  label="Campaign Name"
  name="name"
  type="text"
  ng-model="model.createCampaign.name"
  placeholder="Folow up, cart abandonment etc..."
  required="true"></myinput>
</form>
```

`myinput` is a component:

```
app.component('myinput', {
  templateUrl: 'components/input.html',
  transclude: true,
  bindings: {
    disabled: '<',
    required: '<',
    ngModel: '=',
    form: '=',
    label: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    type: '@',
    name: '@',
  },
  controller: function () {
  }
});
```

And the component template:

```
<div
  ng-form
  name="{{ $ctrl.form }}">
  <label>
    {{ $ctrl.label }}
    <small ng-if="$ctrl.required">(required)</small>
  </label>
  <input
    ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel"
    name="{{ $ctrl.name }}"
    type="{{ $ctrl.type }}"
    placeholder="{{ $ctrl.placeholder }}"
    required="{{ $ctrl.required }}"
    class="form-control form-control--block form-control--primary">
</div>
```

I want to access myinput's validation state like `createCampaignForm.name.$invalid`.

When I add `form` attribute to myinput, the app acts like it's in an infinite loop. Page loading but it don't finish. And there is no error in browser console.

How can I achieve this?

For example, I have a form, it contains 3 myinput inside it. And I should be able to access all the myinputs' validation state like `createCampaignForm.name.$valid` `createCampaignForm.status.$error` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I changed ng-form attribute and problem solved.

I changed this:

```
<div
  ng-form
  name="{{ $ctrl.form }}">
```

To this:

```
<div
  ng-form="$ctrl.form">
```